# How can I get the list of all the files uploaded in my built.io application?

Tags: ios, file, get, built.io, built.io-backend

I have made an iOS application using built.io. There are several files uploaded in the application. However, i am unable to get the list of all the files uploaded in the app. Could anyone please help?

Comment: where have  you saved file ?

Comment: You could always use a network analyzer like Charlec Proxy, Wire Shark or any of others available for download.

Comment: I have created an application using built.io (it's an MBaaS provider). In my application, users upload their files and attach it to objects. I am unable to get this list of all the uploads in the SDK. It is not related to sniffing the network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done via BuiltFile class instance method fetchAllOnSuccess:onError:

It returns all files uploaded in your built application only if the requesting user has permission for it.

```
Built* builtfileObj = [Built file];

[builtfileObj fetchAllOnSuccess:^(NSArray *allFiles) {
    // allFiles contains array of BuiltFiles
} onError:^(NSError *error) {
    // there was an error in creating the object
    // error.userinfo contains more details regarding the same
}];
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit. This solved my issue. Your answer was helpful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

To fetch all the uploads, the iOS SDK provides an instance method in the *BuiltFile* class. It returns an array of all the uploads.
Here's the link to the official documentation
http://static.built.io/downloads/sdk-docs/ios-docs/Classes/BuiltFile.html#//api/name/fetchAllOnSuccess:onError:

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if its available in the iOS SDK but you can use the REST API to fetch it

Headers :

```
"application_uid: uid" 
"application_api_key: api_key"
```

URL: `GET : https://manage.built.io/v1/uploads?skip=0&limit=50&include_count=true`

Params : skip and limit for pagination and include_count is for getting the total count.

The above url will fetch all types of files

But if you want only images or videos then you can use the below urls

```
https://manage.built.io/v1/uploads/images
https://manage.built.io/v1/uploads/videos
```

I hope i was helpful to you!!

Note : without the headers the API wont work